# MongoClient.connect: Searching for a robust way to reconnect to a MongoDB host

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a long running Node.js server task which connects to various MongoDB hosts with

```
// MongoClient options
// TODO: Unable to verify reconnect options
var clientConnectOptions = {
  autoReconnect: true,
  auto_reconnect: true,
  server: {
    sslKey: fs.readFileSync('X509key.pem'),
    sslCert: fs.readFileSync('X509cert.pem'),
    sslPass: null,
    sslValidate: false,
    checkServerIdentity: false
  },
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
}

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://server:port/test?ssl=prefer', clientConnectOptions, function cbDBConnect (err, db) { ... }
```

If the connection to the MongoDB host interrupts for a short time, my application reconnects as planned. But when the session disconnects for several minutes, the MongoClient does not reconnect any more.

I have looked at various reconnect options, but all attempts failed. How can I code a robust way to reconnect automatically?